# Mocha - Programmatically with Debugging

Tags: mocha.js

I'm using a new Mocha().run() instance to initiate Mocha tests during run time.

However, I am unable to debug these from VS code inspector.

I cannot seem to find information about this either.

Is Mocha not debuggable due to it being run in a separate process?